# Mediawiki: how can I use {{PAGENAME}} as part of the file name in a gallery?

Tags: mediawiki, image-gallery

I have 3 images that start with the PAGENAME and have different endings. Now I want to display them in a gallery like this:

```
<gallery>
File:{{PAGENAME}}.png|Adult
File:{{PAGENAME}} Egg.png|Egg
File:{{PAGENAME}} Baby.png|Baby
</gallery>
```

But the PAGENAME doesn't transclude and the gallery stays empty.
How can I achieve that?

Thanks

edit: I would also like to add the `mode="slideshow"` parameter to it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Html tags have priority in page content parsing, which means that any parser function inside is interpreted as string. So you need to turn them into a parser function, using `#tag`

> {{#tag:gallery | *content* }}

Note that you cannot have literal pipes inside *content*, you have to turn them into a template call, using build-in pipe template:

```
{{!}}
```

You'll end up with this code:

> {{#tag:gallery |
>
> File:{{PAGENAME}}.png{{!}}Adult
>
> File:{{PAGENAME}} Egg.png{{!}}Egg
>
> File:{{PAGENAME}} Baby.png{{!}}Baby
>
> |mode=slideshow}}

Comment: that's why - I'll give it a try. (same as for the <ref> tag...).

btw.: there is already a template for the `{{Pipe}}`: `{{!}}`

Comment: Thanks - it worked without parameterizing. But the moment I want to add parameters (`mode="slideshow"` for example) it expands the closing tag to `</gallery mode="slideshow">` too and it stops working again

Comment: Make sure you pass the parameter after a pipe,  after the main content and without quotes. I updated the code.

Comment: That did it. Thanks